# SQL Collect Values from different rows and update the new one

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have a WordPress database. in postmeta table we have 3 different values for each post. we update our theme 3 times and in each time the post count is different from each other. I want to make this; there are values in one table in different rows:

post id 10 value 1: better-views-count 3455
post id 10 value 2: post_stats 522
post id 10 value 3: post_views_count 52

I want to sum the three and update the result post_views_count.

How I can do it and what the sql should I use it?

I think there is no option to do it with SQL fol 1000 post it should be a php code. But I cannot image the sql which I should use it.

EDITED

---

after I make Some Changes and researches I found a solution:

```
<?php $my_meta = bf_get_post_meta( 'better-views-count' );?>
<BR>
<?php $my_meta2 = bf_get_post_meta( 'post_stats' );?>
<BR>
<?php $my_meta3 = bf_get_post_meta( 'post_views_count' );?>


BETTER:
<?php echo $my_meta ?>
<BR>
POST STATS:<?php echo $my_meta2 ?><BR>
POST VIEW COUNT:<?php echo $my_meta3 ?>
<BR>
TOTAL:
<?php
$a=array("a"=>$my_meta,"b"=>$my_meta2,"c"=>$my_meta3);
$total_sum = array_sum($a);

echo $total_sum;
?>


<?php



$row = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = $post->ID;") );

if ($row) {
    $qry_result = $wpdb->update( 
        wp_postmeta, 
        array( 
            'id' => $row->id,
                     'post_id' => $post->ID ,
                     'meta_key' => "better-views-count",
                     'meta_value' => $total_sum
                       ), 
                 array(
                     '%s',
                     '%s',
                     '%s'
                      )
    );
} else {
    $qry_result = $wpdb->insert( 
        wp_postmeta, 
        array( 
                     'post_id' => $post->ID,
                     'meta_key' => "better-views-count",
                     'meta_value' => $total_sum
        ), 
        array( 
                     '%s',
                     '%s',
                     '%s'
                      )
    );
}

if( false !== $qry_result ) {
$qry_result = true;
}

$response = array( 'success' => $qry_result, 'data' => 'hello' ); //if $data is set
echo $qry_result;

?>
```

the result:

BETTER: 
POST STATS:37
POST VIEW COUNT:909
TOTAL: 946

and it should updated and should be

BETTER: 946
POST STATS:37
POST VIEW COUNT:909
TOTAL: 1892

Answer (score 0):

Use `$wpdb` to calculate the totals for each post.

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN ('".$post_id."') AND meta_key IN ('better-views-count','post_stats','post_views_count') ");

print_r($results);
```

Just place your `$post_id` in place.

Comment: I make an update i can calculate them but I cannot update. I make A page which show to me 500 post and put this in loop of title. and in this page show me the result is not change